# Fundamental matrix solution and commutativity.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Please I have a question.

Let $$y'(t) = M(t)y(t)~~~~~~~~~~~(*)$$ where $M(t)$ is a matrix with continuous entries on the interval $(a,b)$.

Let $Y(t,t_0)$ be its fudamental solution. It is known that if $M(t)$ commutes with $A(t)=\int_{t_0}^t M(s)~ds$, then $$Y(t,t_0) = \exp\left(\int_{t_0}^t M(s)~ds\right)~~t,t_0 \in (a,b)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(**)$$

I know that if $M(t)$ and $A(t)$ do not commute, then it is not possible to have $(**)$. The question I want to ask is this:

> Is it possible to for $Y(t,t_0) = \exp(\int M(s))$ to be a fundamental solution of $(*)$ if $M(t)$ do not commute with $A(t)?$

Comment: To clarify, are you asking "Is $Y(t,t_0) = \exp(\int M(s))$ a fundamental solution of $y' = My$ if $M$ and $A$ do not commute?"

Comment: @BaronVT: Yes please.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. The problem is that the chain rule doesn't work the way you would like it to, i.e.

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \exp(A(t)) \neq A'(t) \exp(A(t)) = M(t) \exp(A(t))
$$

in general.

To see why this is, write out the Taylor expansion for $\exp(A(t))$, and when you have to take the derivative of terms of the form

$$
(A(t))^n
$$

you'll see the problem if you proceed carefully. In particular, it is not true that

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(A(t))^n = n (A(t))^{n-1} A'(t); 
$$

really, one must write, e.g.

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(A(t))^3 = \frac{d}{dt}(A(t)A(t)A(t)) = A'(t)A(t)A(t) + A(t)A'(t)A(t) + A(t)A(t)A'(t)\\ = MA^2 + AMA + A^2M.
$$

It would be nice to think of a concrete counterexample; I'll see what I can come up with.

EDIT: (maybe) a counterexample

$$
M(t) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} t & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)
$$
$$
A(t) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0.5 t^2 & t \\ 0 & t\end{array}\right)
$$
You can check that $MA \neq AM$.

Wolfram alpha gives me
$$
Y(t) = \exp(A(t)) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} e^{0.5 t^2} & -2\frac{e^t - e^{0.5 t^2}}{t-2}
 \\ 0 & e^t\end{array}\right).
$$

Now we need to see if $Y'(t) \neq M(t)Y(t)$ (hopefully it isn't!). I haven't set down and done the calculation, but a little messing around convinced me this probably works out. In particular, it's the entry in the 1st row, 2nd column that won't be equal.

Comment: Thanks. Yea, It'd be nice to have a concrete counterexample. that'll be awesome!

Comment: @Jonny Ok, I edited in the beginnings of a counterexample, though I'll leave it to you to check all the details.

Comment: I checked the details and the matrix you gave does not satisfy the commutativity condition and so cannot give the fundamental solution, but this doesn't solve my question. I want to know if I can have a matrix $M(t)$ such that the commutativity condition doesn't hold but $Y'(t)=M(t)Y(t)$

Comment: Ok, so if you know that $Y(t) = \int(M)$ is not a fundamental solution (and so we cannot have $Y' = MY$), then what sort of $Y$ are you looking for when you say "the commutativity condition doesn't hold but $Y′(t)=M(t)Y(t)$ " ?

Comment: Perhaps there's a misunderstanding. I am trying to find $M(t)$ such that $M(t)A(t) \neq A(t)M(t)$ but we still have $Y(t)= \exp(A(t))$.

Comment: You can always *define* $Y(t) := \exp(A(t))$, but what properties do you want it to satisfy? It will *not* satisfy $Y' = MY$.